# MS Access import csv ad overwriting data in tables

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Currently I am working with 3 CSV files that are updated daily, but some of the data will stay in there for up to 10 days or loner. The problem that I've ran into is that every time I import the CSV files, it will duplicate the previous data. Is there to tell it not to duplicate the data or to just over write the data that is the same in the CSV? I've attached a copy of the code I'm using for it.

Import_Ovens

Function Import_Ovens()

On Error GoTo Import_Ovens_Err

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Time", "Oven1", "\\****\data\oven1.csv", True, ""
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Time", "Oven2", "\\****\data\oven2.csv", True, ""
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Time", "Oven3", "\****\data\oven3.csv", True, ""
```

Import_Ovens_Exit:

```
Exit Function
```

Import_Ovens_Err:

```
MsgBox Error$

Resume Import_Ovens_Exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of importing it, link to the text file (different table name).

```
DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, "Time", "Oven1_temp", "\\****\data\oven1.csv", True, ""
```

Then run an append query checking against the table if it already exists. It would liik something like this:

```
INSERT INTO oven1
SELECT [oven1-temp].*
FROM [oven1-temp] LEFT JOIN oven1 ON [oven1-temp].ID = oven1.ID
WHERE (((oven1.ID) Is Null));
```